# nvidia-smi stopped working after installing cuda-toolkit

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, cuda, hardware-enablement-stack

**TLDR**

I'm trying to get `nvidia-smi` back up, which was working fine until I installed cuda-toolkit. Uninstalling cuda-toolkit didn't help. **How can I restore `nvidia-smi` output?**

> NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA
> driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and
> running.

---

### More details

I've GEFORCE RTX 2070 on my laptop running Ubuntu 18.04 and had successfully installed its driver from the official runfile `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.63.01.run`. Here is the output of `nvidia-smi` from that installation:

[image]

Next, I installed cuda-toolkit from the official runfile `cuda_11.4.2_470.57.02_linux.run`, making sure to ***un-select*** driver installation. Here's the terminal window right after installation completed:

[image]

Right after, when I did `nvidia-smi`, I get:

> NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA
> driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and
> running.

Since it was cuda-toolkit's installation that presumably "broke" `nvidia-smi`, I uninstalled cuda-toolkit (by running `cuda-uninstaller` found in `/usr/local/cuda-11.4/bin`, as stated in the generated text after installation).

Unfortunately, that doesn't help and `nvidia-smi` is still corrupted. The reason I'm installing from official NVIDIA runfiles is because previously I had issues installing driver from Ubuntu repositories, but could make it work with the official driver. So I figured I'd try the same with cuda-toolkit.

**How can I get back `nvidia-smi`?**

### Outputs of some commands, if relevant

- **`which nvidia-smi`**  :  `/usr/bin/nvidia-smi`
- **`mokutil --sb-state`**  :  `SecureBoot disabled`
- **`nvidia-settings`**  :

  - `ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded`
  - `ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system`
- **`ls /sys/firmware/efi/`**  :

  - `config_table  efivars  esrt  fw_platform_size  fw_vendor  runtime  runtime-map  systab  vars`
- **`lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'`**  :

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CometLake-H GT2
> [UHD Graphics] (rev 05)
> Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 12ae
> Kernel driver in use: i915
>
> 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU106M [GeForce RTX 2070 Mobile / > Max-Q Refresh] (rev a1)
> Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 12ae
> Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau

- **`cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf`**  :

> blacklist nouveau
> blacklist vga16b
> blacklist rivafb
> blacklist nvidiafb
> blacklist rivatv
> blacklist amd76_edac
> alias nouveau off
> alias lbm-nouveau off
> options nouveau modeset=0

- **`cat /proc/version`**  :

  - `Linux version 5.4.0-84-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-007) (gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)) #94~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 26 23:17:46 UTC 2021`
- **`sudo lshw -c video`**  : (NVIDIA display is "unclaimed", but [this is how](https://www.linuxbabe.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/nvidia-driver-ubuntu-18.04.webp) it should be)

[image]

- **`dkms status`**  :  no output
- **`lsmod | grep nvidia`**  :

  - `i2c_nvidia_gpu         16384  0`
- **`echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`**  :  `x11`
- **`whereis nvidia`**  :

  - `nvidia: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia /usr/lib/nvidia /usr/share/nvidia /usr/src/nvidia-470.63.01/nvidia`
- **`grep nvidia /etc/modprobe.d/* /lib/modprobe.d/*`**:

> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-framebuffer.conf:blacklist nvidiafb
> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf:blacklist nvidiafb
> /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-installer-disable-nouveau.conf:# generated by nvidia-installer
> /lib/modprobe.d/nvidia-runtimepm.conf:options nvidia  "NVreg_DynamicPowerManagement=0x02"

### Posts / Questions I've already looked at:

- ["NVIDIA-SMI has failed" after installing cuda 10.0](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218533/nvidia-smi-has-failed-after-installing-cuda-10-0)
- [CUDA & Nvidia Installation Unsuccessful and nvidia-smi Error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135018/cuda-nvidia-installation-unsuccessful-and-nvidia-smi-error)
- [Nvidia driver installs but does not load on ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040515/nvidia-driver-installs-but-does-not-load-on-ubuntu-18-04) : most voted answer seems to have problems later

Comment: Your system /usr/bin/gcc --version should be 9.3.0, and if you altered your PATH, maybe gcc --version might be some other, but not 7.5.  When altering the gcc version for CUDA, do not alter the system default (never use /etc/alternatives for gcc!!!!). Manipulate CUDA's gcc via the cuda/bin having links (or executables) to the required version. The Nvidia driver number in the standard repos is 470.63.01, so I'd use that after cleaning out all the existing Nvidia packges.

Comment: Alright so `gcc --version` was indeed 7.5. To upgrade to 9 (which was already installed) I used `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-9 9` and `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-9 9` so now `/usr/bin/gcc --version` and `/usr/bin/g++ --version` return 9.4.0. The error with nvidia-smi remains though. Does the driver require a re-install?

Driver-installation isn't a quick and easy process - at least for me - so that's something I'd do only if I have to

Comment: My confusion, your kernel made me think 20.04 with default gcc 9.3. I added the HWE and 18.04 tags.  I don't use any HWE, so not sure how that works --, demanding one default compiler version for the kernel/modules(9.3), and another for the rest of the system (7.5?). Not sure where your gcc 9.4 ver came from unless it's for a HWE for 21.04 (but then why didn't the kernel update?). I suppose it would be possible to use update-alternatives 9.3 for gcc, --reconfigure the nvidia-driver-470 package to recompile, then switch back to the 7.5 gcc for the rest of the system.

Comment: Thanks for adding the tags. "reconfigure the nvidia-driver-470 to recompile" -- hm since `nvidia-settings` doesn't work (output included in question) I'm not sure how I'd do that.

Answer (score 6):

I purged all nvidia stuff and then tried `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` followed by `sudo reboot` after which `nvidia-smi` works fine.

[image]

So I guess the solution was to re-install NVIDIA drivers.

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me too on Ubuntu 22.04.2.
`sudo apt remove --purge nvidia* && sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall && sudo reboot`